# Select Additional Rows Based Upon INT Difference Between Two Columns

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset that is structured like this:

```
Make|StartYear|EndYear
----------------------
AA  | 2000    | 2005
AB  | 1984    | 1989
AR  | 1965    | 1966
BC  | 1999    | 2000
```

The Year columns are currently stored as INT format.  I am trying to return a dataset structured like so via a SELECT:

```
Make|StartYear|EndYear|Year
----------------------|------
AA  | 2000    | 2005  | 2000
AA  | 2000    | 2005  | 2001
AA  | 2000    | 2005  | 2002
AA  | 2000    | 2005  | 2003
AA  | 2000    | 2005  | 2004
AA  | 2000    | 2005  | 2005
AB  | 1984    | 1989  | 1984
----------------------------------
AB  | 1984    | 1989  | 1988
AB  | 1984    | 1989  | 1989
```

etc

Is there anyway that this could be achieved with MySQL?

Comment: What do you want to do this for? I can't say for certain, but this might be something better handled at the presentation layer? I'm not quite sure why you would need to display everything in between though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.. I am using a temp table.. and an SP.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `mytest`()
BEGIN


declare _make varchar(20);
declare _startyear int;
declare _endyear int;
DECLARE bDone INT;
DECLARE ioffset INT;

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  SELECT make, startyear, endyear  FROM test.maketable;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpmake;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpmake AS  
    SELECT make, startyear, endyear, startyear as theyear from test.maketable;


 OPEN curs;

  SET bDone = 0;
  REPEAT
    FETCH curs INTO _make,_startyear, _endyear;
    Set ioffset = 1;
    While (_startyear + ioffset <= _endyear and bDone = 0) do
      Insert into tmpmake values (_make,_startyear, _endyear, _startyear + ioffset);
      Set ioffset = ioffset + 1;
    end while;

  UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;

  CLOSE curs;
  SELECT * FROM tmpmake order by 1,4;
-- 
--  
END
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Have learnt a bunch of new things from this too.  Thanks!